How do I grab text dimensions dynamically before writing to an image in Python's Pillow Library?
I want to write text to a blank new image dynamically using Python's Imaging Library. The process would work as such:

Specify text (is a representation of an ascii image)
Select/load font with ImageFont.truetype
Get the dimensions, n, of the text given the selected font
Create a blank image of dimensions n
Write said text over the image

The issue I'm running into is with stage 3 onward: getting the dimensions and then writing.
For further context, I'd like the ascii text image to be stored as a list (to be rejoined with '\n'.join(), or a string containing '\n' newline escaped characters.
I have attempted this in two ways:

Using ImageFont's getbbox method

Using ImageDraw's multiline methods


In the absence of ImageFont's getsize method, I attempted to use getbbox. This does not seem to handle new lines particularly well.
Running the getbbox method seems to return a plausible pixel width, but height does not seem to increment upwardly regardless of the number of lines.
Here is what I tried first:
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont

image_lines = [] #is a list of strings where each string represents a row of the ascii image
text = '\n'.join(image_lines)

font_path = CourierPrime-Regular.ttf
font = ImageFont.truetype(font_path,size=3)

text_dimensions = font.getbbox(text)
text_width = text_dimensions[2] - text_dimensions[0]
text_height = text_dimensions[3] - text_dimensions[1]

print(f'TEXT WIDTH: {text_width}\nTEXT HEIGHT: {text_height}') #height remains the same regardless of line count

In this case, text_dimensions contains the four tuple: (left,lower,right,upper), hence, text_width represents (right - left) and
text_height represents (upper-lower)
It seems that no matter how many lines I add to 'text', the height characteristic remains constant.
After reading the documentation further for the ImageDraw module, I came across several multiline methods (namely multiline_textbox and multiline_text). I figured that I could:

pass the text into the multiline_textbox method using a dummy image in order to get the dimensions,

create new blank image of dimensions equivalent to the textbox

write multiline text to the image using multiline_text


Here is what I tried next:
from PIL import Image, ImageFont, ImageDraw


image_lines = [] #list containing strings, where each string represents a row of the ascii image
text = '\n'.join(image_lines)

font_path = r'CourierPrime-Regular.ttf'
font = ImageFont.truetype(font_path,size=3)

#dummy image, needed to construct Draw object
img = Image.new('RGB',(1,1)) 
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)

#check for text dimensions
text_dimensions = draw.multiline_textbbox((0,0), 
                                          text=text,
                                          font=font)
text_width = text_dimensions[2] - text_dimensions[0]
text_height = text_dimensions[3] - text_dimensions[1]

#for debugging
print(f'TEXT WIDTH: {text_width}\nTEXT HEIGHT: {text_height}')
print(text_dimensions)

#creating new image of required size and new Draw object
img = Image.new('RGB',
                (text_width,text_height),
                color='#000000')
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)

#drawing text over image
draw.multiline_text((0,0),
                    text=text,
                    fill='#ffffff',
                    font=font)

img.show()

This seems to work conceptually, but I am running into some issues with scaling when altering font size (set within the variable 'font').
When increasing the font size, the image seems to manipulated - appears stretched horizontally (squashed vertically) as font size increases.
I wondered whether this might be caused by the specific font itself (the way the font scales) - or whether I've overlooked something to do with line spacing.

Is the second approach viable?

How would I go about addressing the scaling/squashing issue so that the text image is displayed as in the .txt file of the same contents.



The actual range to draw the text is not the bbox the text, so it won't fit the full text into the Image object whose size is defined only the bbox of the text, so using different anchor coordinates or offset to draw the image here.
Example Code
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont, ImageTk
import tkinter as tk

def image(text="Hello\nWorld", size=3, font_path=r"C:\Windows\Fonts\cour.ttf"):
    font = ImageFont.truetype(font=font_path, size=size)
    im = Image.new('RGB', (1,1))
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
    box = draw.multiline_textbbox((0,0), text=text, font=font)
    offset = (-box[0], -box[1])
    size = (box[2]-box[0], box[3]-box[1])
    im = Image.new('RGB', size, color='#000000')
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
    draw.multiline_text(offset, text=text, fill='#ffffff', font=font, align="center")
    return ImageTk.PhotoImage(im)

lines = ["We'll have a good night", "and", "a merry Christmas time"]
text = '\n'.join(lines)

root = tk.Tk()
root.configure(background="green")
images = []
for size in [16, 24, 40]:
    img = image(text, size)
    images.append(img)
    label = tk.Label(image=img, bd=1)
    label.pack()

root.mainloop()


